# How to integrate google Checkout API in PHP

Tags: php, google-api

I am trying to integrate Google Checkout API in PHP. I need to send some input values from form like item name, item price,item quantity to Google checkout.

Please suggest me some link or code to workaround it....

```
$item_1 = new GoogleItem($item,      // Item name
                           $itemdesc, // Item      description
                           $total_count, // Quantity
                           10); // Unit price
```

Comment: What have you got so far or what isn't working? You really should post your code in your question.

Comment: `$item_1 = new GoogleItem($item,      // Item name
                           $itemdesc, // Item      description
                           $total_count, // Quantity
                           10); // Unit price `

Answer (score 0):

[Google offers sample code](https://google-developers.appspot.com/checkout/samples/Google_Checkout_Sample_Code_PHP) which was easy to find when I searched for it

Comment: $item_1 = new GoogleItem($item,      // Item name 
                           $itemdesc, // Item      description
                           $total_count, // Quantity
                           10); // Unit price